# WM_IME_KEYDOWN not capturing arrow keys

Tags: c#, ime

I am trying to capture the arrow keys when using IME, however the WM_IME_KEYDOWN doesn't seem to capture the arrows. I tried with WM_IME_COMPOSITION which do happen when pressing an arrow but I could not see which arrow was pressed.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
    if (m.Msg == WM_IME_KEYDOWN) {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use low level keyboard hook instead.

Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804).